# Creating Transactions from multiple vectors in R

Tags: r

Suppose, I have multiple vectors like

```
v1 <- c(1:10)
v2 <- c(1:23)
v3 <- c(10:40)
```

I want to convert these vectors into a single transaction object. How can I do it? I have searched some on the internet, but I only find ways of converting data frames, data tables into transactions. Also, these vectors `v1`, `v2` and `v3` are for explaining the question. Actually, data is produced by python script and consists of multiple sets of different length. I don't know of an efficient way to store that data in `R` and convert them to transactions. After converting them to transactions, I aim to run `apriori` for association rule mining.

Comment: what is a transaction object ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the arules package on how to create an transaction class object (pdf pages 91 / 92 or `?transactions`) you can just convert a list object to a transaction class.

So first you need to get all your vectors into a list, which can be done like this:

```
var_names <- ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = "^v[[:digit:]]+")
my_list <- mget(var_names, envir = globalenv())
```

Next rename the list names to transactions:

```
names(my_list) <- paste("Tr", seq_along(my_list), sep = "")
```

And finally coerce the list to a transaction class object:

```
library(arules)
trans1 <- as(my_list, "transactions")

trans1
transactions in sparse format with
 3 transactions (rows) and
 40 items (columns)
```